# Set HtttpHeader's `renderInResponses` with akka-http-server

Tags: playframework, http-headers, akka, akka-http

I tried to set a `HttpHeader` to result in Play 2.5.15:

> Ok.withHeaders("Authorization" -> "XXXXXX")

When run the app with akka-http server backend, I got

> [warn] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - HTTP header 'Authorization: XXXXXX' is not allowed in responses

and the header is not included at the client side.
After digging a bit I found that akka-http (`HttpResponseRendererFactory`) checks for the header's `renderInResponses` which is `false` in my case.
Furthermore, Play doesn't allow me to provide a custom `HttpHeader` to the `Result`, all I can give are the header name and value.

So how can I sneak my header into the `HttpResponse` to akka-http? Thank you in advance!